why does num_train_epoch always save the latest value instead of corresponding value of maximum acuracy. how to capture the correct epoch value
here are my arguments
args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="bert-finetuned-ner",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    save_total_limit=3,
    metric_for_best_model="eval_accuracy", # load model with highest accuracy score
    load_best_model_at_end=True, # load model with highest accuracy score
    learning_rate=best_params['learning_rate'],
    num_train_epochs=best_params['num-train_epoch'],  
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_steps=10,
    logging_strategy="epoch",
    fp16=True
)
trainer = Trainer(
    model_init=model_init,
    args=args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["test"],
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics_all,
    tokenizer=tokenizer
    )

this is after the objective function where in training to capture
with mlflow.start_run(run_id=parent_run.info.run_id, nested=True) as run:
    # log run name
    mlflow.set_tag('mlflow.runName', run_name)
    
    # Log tokenizer parameters
    tokenizer_params = {
        "padding_side": tokenizer.padding_side,
        "truncation_side": tokenizer.truncation_side
    }
    mlflow.log_params(tokenizer_params)

    # train
    trainer.train()

    # log best params
    mlflow.log_params(best_params)

    # Evaluate and log all metrics
    results = trainer.evaluate()
    for key, value in results.items():
        mlflow.log_metric(key, value)

how to capture the correct epoch value in mlflow instead of the latest epoch value of the best trial with epoch value corresponding to highest accuracy. If it needs to corrected in the objective fuction itself then please illustrate how to do that correction step.when logging also this causes the issue.df1 = study.trials_dataframe()
